# PHP outputting the code and not a proper output

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new to PHP. I've been trying to get this mailer to work and I have gotten most of it working. 
Here is my PHP:

```
    <?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $included_files = get_included_files();

    foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'rottenrobbie911@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465; 

    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('yalnifcam2@gmail.com', 'Joe User');

    $mail->Subject = 'GenericSubject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
    ?>
```

When I run my code here without a password this comes up:

```
    /var/www/html/mail.php /var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions_include.php /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php /var/www/html/vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random.php /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions_include.php /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php /var/www/html/vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid/lib/SendGrid.php /var/www/html/vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid/lib/helpers/mail/Mail.php /var/www/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php /var/www/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php
    Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

But put a password in and it doesn't like it. Instead prints the code to the webpage like so.

```
isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication $mail->Username = 'rottenrobbie911@gmail.com'; // SMTP username $mail->Password = 'password';
// SMTP password $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted $mail->Port = 465; $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer'); $mail->addAddress('yalnifcam2@gmail.com', 'Joe User'); $mail->Subject 
= 'GenericSubject'; $mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body in bold!'; if(!$mail->send()) { echo 'Message could not be sent.'; echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; } else { echo 'Message has been sent'; } ?>
```

It's just the password. When I enter a password it doesn't work but leave it bank and it just fails to authenticate.

Comment: You might need to post screenshots as well

Comment: I would but it is difficult on this particular computer. I will If Sahil's fix doesn't work

Comment: It would help if you read the troubleshooting guide the error message links you to, and base your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer. If you set `SMTPDebug = 2` you'll have much more info about where the problem is. Also why are you you including SwiftMailer as well as PHPMailer? Pick one!

Answer (score 0):

[Reference gmail smtp settings](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854)

Use port no `587` for `TLS`.

change this `$mail->Port = 465;` to `$mail->Port = 587;`

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. The problem seems to be with the password. I changed mail servers and when I don't put a password in like: this $mail->Password = ''; then it seems to work but won't authenticate. Put a password in and none of it works.

Comment: @Yalnix I was expecting that you are using correct password.